# Solr dataimport and SQL with xml escape

Tags: sql, xml, solr, data-import, ucanaccess

I tried the following SQL in entity tag of dataimport config file:

```
<entity name="Page" dataSource="a1" query="SELECT &amp;apos;26484-&amp;apos;&amp;amp;`book`.id&amp;amp;&amp;apos;-&amp;apos;&amp;amp;`book`.page&amp;amp;&amp;apos;-&amp;apos;&amp;amp;`book`.part AS PageID, `book`.id AS pid, `book`.nass AS Content, `book`.part AS Part, `book`.page AS PageNum FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.id, `book`.page">
```

The Sql query contains characters should be escaped in xml, `' and &`. However, I recive the following error in the log:

```
 DocBuilder     Exception while processing: Page document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT '26484-'&`book`.id&'-'&`book`.page&'-'&`book`.part AS PageID,​ `book`.id AS pid,​ `book`.nass AS Content,​ `book`.part AS Part,​ `book`.page AS PageNum FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.id,​ `book`.page Processing Document # 1
```

and

```
DataImporter    Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT '26484-'&`book`.id&'-'&`book`.page&'-'&`book`.part AS PageID,​ `book`.id AS pid,​ `book`.nass AS Content,​ `book`.part AS Part,​ `book`.page AS PageNum FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.id,​ `book`.page Processing Document # 1
```

I use [ucanaccess](/questions/tagged/ucanaccess) jdbc driver.

When I tried to remove concatination from the SQL query so, removing the escaped characters, I have not got this error, but I have got solrWriter warning about duplicate Unique key. and I understand this warning. However, How could I able to write use the Sql query shown above?

Comment: There is no need to escape single quotes, you can put `'` directly into the query.

Comment: And a `&` is required for every escaped character. So you will need to replace `&amp;apos;` with `&amp;&apos;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no need to escape single quotes, you can put `'` directly into the query.
2. A `&` is required for every escaped character. So you will need to replace `&amp;apos;` with `&amp;&apos;`.

The fact that corrupts your query should be (2).

```xml
<entity name="Page" dataSource="a1" query="SELECT &amp;'26484-&amp;'&amp;&amp;`book`.id&amp;&amp;&amp;'-&amp;'&amp;&amp;`book`.page&amp;&amp;&amp;'-&amp;'&amp;&amp;`book`.part AS PageID, `book`.id AS pid, `book`.nass AS Content, `book`.part AS Part, `book`.page AS PageNum FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.id, `book`.page">
```